# Creating a JSON result from SQL server database

Tags: c#, javascript, sql, json, razor

I have an SQL server with the following layout

```
Table (    id int
           title varchar(40),
           start Date(),
           end Date(),
           allDay bool,
           username varchar(40)
      );
```

I have gotten the following code from [this blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/02/03/using-fullcalendar-jquery-component-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx) to create a JSON object from the data I wish to use, however his data is stored differently. How do I create the same object, extracted from my database?

I am guessing I need to make the file a .cshtml file rather than a .js file and use this :

```
@{
    var db = Database.Open("events"); 
    var selectQueryString = "SELECT * FROM events";
}

 @foreach(var row in db.Query(selectQueryString)){ }
```

But how do I adapt this code to produce the same JSON object?

Here is the relevant code from the blog, my attempt is below :

```
public JsonResult GetEvents(double start, double end)
{
    var userName = Session["UserName"] as string;
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
    {
        return null;
    }

    var fromDate = ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(start);
    var toDate = ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(end);

    var rep = Resolver.Resolve<IEventRepository>();
    var events = rep.ListEventsForUser(userName,fromDate,toDate);

    var eventList = from e in events
                    select new {
                                id = e.Id,
                                title = e.Title,
                                start = e.FromDate.ToString("s"),
                                end = e.ToDate.ToString("s"),
                                allDay = false
                            }; 

    var rows = eventList.ToArray();
    return Json(rows,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);           
}
```

Edit :

I am now working with the following .cshtml code for the GetEvents command, but it will not work. Does anybody have any ideas ?

```
   @{ 
        var origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        var fromDate = origin.AddSeconds((Request["start"]));
        var toDate = origin.AddSeconds(Request["end"]);

        var db = Database.Open("events");
        var result = db.Query("SELECT * FROM events");
        var data = result.Select(x => new 
        {
            id = x.id,
            title = x.title,
            start = x.start.ToString("s"),
            end = x.end.ToString("s"),
            allDay = false            
        }).ToArray();

        Json.Write(data, Response.Output);
        Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with [`JavacriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)?

Comment: How would I use JavascriptSerializer in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no controllers and actions in WebMatrix WebPages. You need to write a separate `.cshtml` page that will query the database and serve the JSON to the response:

```
@{
    var db = Database.Open("events");
    var result = db.Query("SELECT * FROM events");
    var data = result.Select(x => new 
    {
        id = x.id,
        title = x.title,
        start = x.start.ToString("s"),
        end = x.end.ToString("s"),
        allDay = false            
    }).ToArray();

    Json.Write(data, Response.Output);
    Response.ContentType = "application/json";
}
```

and then in another page in which you want to display the calendar you could configure it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {             
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({ 
        theme: true, 
        header: { 
            left: '', 
            center: '', 
            right: '' 
        }, 
        defaultView: 'agendaDay', 
        editable: false, 
        events: '/events.cshtml' 
    }); 
});
```

---

UPDATE: Here's an example of how you could use parametrized queries:

```
@{

    var origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    var fromDate = origin.AddSeconds(int.Parse(Request["start"]));
    var toDate = origin.AddSeconds(int.Parse(Request["end"]));
    var db = Database.Open("events");
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE start >= @0 AND end <= @1";
    var result = db.Query(sql, fromDate, toDate);
    var data = result.Select(x => new 
    {
        id = x.id,
        title = x.title,
        start = x.start.ToString("s"),
        end = x.end.ToString("s"),
        allDay = false            
    }).ToArray();

    Json.Write(data, Response.Output);
    Response.ContentType = "application/json";
}
```

Now you could query the page like this: `/events.cshtml?start=5&end=10`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried to integrate your code into mine, but it does not appear to be working, unfortunately - there are no events being produced for the calendar. I have two theories - the first is that the start/end times are stored differently and need to be changed, and the second is that in the first .cshtml file, containing the connection to the database, it doesn't seem to be returning anything? Do you have any ideas, as I have been slaving on this since your response to no avail! Thank you very much for the response :)

Comment: Also, in my code above, the start and end time of the current view are provided as parameters, but in your C# function, this data appears not to be used at all?

Comment: @SimonKiely, in your updated answer you seem to be using something that doesn't look much like C# syntax. You concatenate the SQL string with dots. Also you seem to be calling the `ConvertFromUnixTimestamp` function with undefined variables: `start` and `end`. If you wanted to read this from the request you would have used `Request["start"]` and `Request["end"]`. I would recommend you though to first get this working without additional filtering parameters. Also you wrapped the code in a HTML file and haven't returned the JSON data. Also look with FireBug if the script sends correct JSON.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. I have edited the code above, but I still cannot seem to get it to retrieve any events and display them on screen. Apologies for my mistakes, I am a Java programmer working in C#, new to JavaScript, so it's quite confusing for me! Do you have any ideas what might be wrong with my code above? I have saved the JSON creator in a .CSHTML file, the database has been populated, but I can't seem to get anywhere. Thank you so much for your help so far, I am very appreciative.

Comment: @SimonKiely, see my updated answer for an example of how to properly use parametrized queries with web pages. Also you can put breakpoints in your code and try to debug it.

Comment: thank you for the response! I am trying first to get it working just via selecting * from events, do you think this is a good course of action? My code is above, but I am not getting anywhere. I was under the impression, from the blog that the start and end time were sent alongside the call to events/GetEvents?

Comment: I am learning to debug this as I go, apologies. The message I am getting is "Compiler Error Message: </b>CS1502: The best overloaded method match for System.DateTime.AddSeconds(double) has some invalid arguments". So Request["Start"] must not be working as I thought?

Comment: @SimonKiely, if you want to get it working with a simple `select * from events` why are you trying to use Request parameters and so on. The `AddSeconds` parameter expects an integer. `Request["start"]` returns a string. In my answer I have shown an example of how to parse this string using the `int.Parse` method. Also I don't know why you are trying to invoke `events/GetEvents` wheres you should be calling the `events.cshtml` page directly.

Comment: Firebug is fantastic! I now have it rendering all events at the correct times, but not for specific users - fantastic! :) Thank you for all the help! :)

Comment: Yes, I completely agree with you that FireBug is fantastic. If you want to render it for specific user you could use the username column in your SQL query to constrain the resultset.

Comment: Just one final question about the SQL query -  var sql = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE start >= @0 AND end <= @1"; is giving me an error. I have tried removing the params from strings, but it is still returning an error.Compiler Error Message: CS1646: Keyword, identifier, or string expected after verbatim specifier: @. Thank you so much for your help - I owe you very much :)

Comment: @SimonKiely, you need to pass the arguments values when calling the db.Query method. The first argument is the sql string and then you can have a variable number of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @listCol VARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(4000)

SELECT  @listCol = STUFF(( SELECT distinct  '], [' + [PSize]
                           FROM     Pattern
                         FOR
                           XML PATH('')
                         ), 1, 2, '') + ']'


SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM
      (SELECT PColour as Colour_Size_Matrix, PSize, PCode
            FROM Pattern
            ) src
PIVOT (Count(PCode) FOR PSize
IN (' + @listCol + ')) AS pvt'

EXECUTE ( @query )
```

I want the result of this query as JSON