# How can I debug my code using WebMatrix and Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio, debugging, razor

I am currently writing some code in a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416380/creating-a-json-result-from-sql-server-database). The code is employing the [fullcalendar JQuery plugin](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/). I am trying to adapt it to use C# and an SQL server as its feed. I have a .cshtml file, which reads from a database, creates a JSON object from the data and returns this to the JQuery plugin.

The kicker for me, is that I am a Java/PHP programmer, who has never worked using JavaScript, C# or Visual Studio before (and probably never will again!) so really I am fighting blind in trying to debug my code. I was hoping someone here could help me to help myself!

At the moment, I am using WebMatrix as an IDE and trying to execute my code after every change. What are better ways that I can test this code?

Edit : I  am now using Firebug, it's great! Does anyone have any more tips?

Answer (score 0):

You can do old school print statements using the javascript alerts, http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp , or simply print stuff out as plaintext in the HTML.

Inspired by http://saucelabs.com/blog/index.php/2012/05/goodbye-couchdb/ , I am storing raw JSON to the DB.

WebMatrix has a nice quickref page, http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/more-resources/asp-net-web-pages-api-reference.

Mike Brind's book and webpage, http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/160/WebMatrix-Working-With-The-JSON-Helper , are also great references.